# Prevent automatic String to Integer conversion in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple POJO:

```
public class ADate {
    private Integer day;
    private Integer month;
    private Integer year;
    ... // getters/setters/constructor
}
```

The following JSON Document gets deserialized correctly into `ADate`:

```
{ 
  "day":"10", 
  "month":"2", 
  "year":"1972"
}
```

Jackson converts the String into Integer automatically.

Is there a way to avoid this automatic conversion and have Jackson to fail if the Integer values are defined as String.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want the integer as a string or not? In any case there is a configuration in the mapper for that :
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();      mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true);`
Or false if you don't want it as String

Comment: The setting doesn't seem to make any difference. Basically I don't want the system to accept a document with Strings in place of numbers

Comment: Do you fix your problem? Im facing the same behavior and cant find configuration to disable this..

Answer (score 7):

There is a configuration setting on the ObjectMapper called the `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS`. If set to `false`, it will prevent ObjectMapper from coercing String representations of numbers and booleans into their Java counterparts. Only strict conversions will be allowed.

Exact usage example:

```
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, false);
```

References:

[1] *Add `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS` for enabling/disabling coercions #1106*: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1106

[2] *Prevent coercion of `int` from empty String to `null` if `DeserializationFeature .FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES` is `true` #1095:* https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1095

[3] *ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS* http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/

Answer (score 5):

I've found the some interesting code on Jackson github [issues](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/796). Changed it a little and that's what I got:

```
public class ForceIntegerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Integer> {

    @Override
    public int deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
            throw deserializationContext.wrongTokenException(jsonParser, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING, "Attempted to parse String to int but this is forbidden");
        }
        return jsonParser.getValueAsInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this file and how to use it with my Spring boot project?

Comment: @AbhisekRoy put it anywhere inside component scan with the JsonComponent annotation

Comment: And add annotations to use it for each variable in model right?