# Json deserialization must throw exception on wrong types

Tags: java, json, jackson

I ran into such a problem. For example, I have a class:

```
class User {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

I deserialize json strings to my class this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
```

But when I send for example a number in a string for name, or a number as a string for id, it casts them to the right types, but I need to throw exception in this case.
This kind of json should result in exception:

```
{ "id": "123","name": 123 }
```

But in my case it works. I would be grateful for any tips on how to deal with it.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597779/prevent-automatic-string-to-integer-conversion-in-jackson