# Hashmap: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to do simple edit for my web application for that i am getting stringify data from frontend, so i converted it into object but then i am getting id as Long value.my code works fine with add new data but whenever i tried to edit it gives error
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.
Please check the screenshot i provided.

**Controller.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String managePostProduct(@RequestParam(name = "data", required = false) String add,
        @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(add);
        Addproductdetails detail = new Addproductdetails();
        OurProducts mProduct = detail.addproduct(obj, file);

        if (mProduct.getId() == 0) {

            productDAO.addOurProducts(mProduct);

        } else {
            productDAO.update(mProduct);
        }

        if (!mProduct.getFile().getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
            FileUploadUtility.uploadFile(request, mProduct.getFile(), mProduct.getCode());
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/manage/product?success=product";
}
```

**Addproductdetails,java**

```
    public OurProducts addproduct(Object obj , MultipartFile file) {
    ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> prod = oMapper.convertValue(obj, HashMap.class);

    System.out.println("prod "+ prod);
    OurProducts product = new OurProducts();

    if (prod.containsKey("id")) {           
        System.out.println("product === " + prod.values());
    }
    
    int id = prod.containsKey("id") && !prod.get("id").isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt((String) prod.get("id")) : 0;
    product.setId(id);
    product.setProduct_name(prod.get("product_name"));
    product.setProduct_info(prod.get("product_info"));
    product.setFile(file);
    return product; 
}
```

**breakpoints**

[image]

please tell me why i am getting id as Long value? How can i fix it?

Comment: Jackson auto convert numerical string. Seems like [Prevent automatic String to Integer conversion in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597779/prevent-automatic-string-to-integer-conversion-in-jackson)

Comment: Because the value is numerical in your JSON? If you want more control, map to a properly annotated POJO instead of a `HashMap`. Possibly mapping to a type reference of a `HashMap<String, String>` might also work. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `id` field from client with type of `Long` and trying to put it into an `int` type.
If you can change `Product` class, I recommend to change its `id` field type to `long` so that no casting is needed also you might face data loss in casting `long` to `int`.

by the way if you can not change your code or don't want to, here you can fix the problem:

instead of:

```
int id = prod.containsKey("id") && !prod.get("id").isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt((String) prod.get("id")) : 0;
```

use this:

```
int id = prod.containsKey("id") && !prod.get("id").isEmpty() ? (int) prod.get("id") : 0;
```

good luck

Comment: the output of `prod.get("id")` is long, isn't it?

Comment: If you check screenshot i am getting key : id and value: Long   instead of actual id eg, value: 4

Comment: check the updated answer, please and let me know the results

Comment: prod.get("id") is long but it prints nothing i got error on that line when i tried to print it.

Comment: @Milgo i got java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String when i tried to print id