# Why integer values are converting into string in json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is class called Smets2ConnectionStatusModel

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Smets2ConnectionStatusModel {
    private long timestamp;
    private smHanState smHanState;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class smHanState {
        private String state;
        private String subState;
        private long stateChangeTime;
        private float hanSignalStrength;
        private Integer hanRSSI;
        private Integer hanLQI;
    }
}
```

In my API I'm passing values in JSON format (hardcoded):

```java
@Timed
@PostMapping(value = "/status")
public void handleSESignalStrength() {
    log.info("Get status");
    String message = "{\"timestamp\":1615978156,\"smHanState\":{\"state\":1,\"subState\":\"lowfreqmode\",\"stateChangeTime\":1615978156,\"hanSignalStrCategory\":\"none\",\"hanRSSI\":0,\"hanLQI\":0}};
}
```

As I have mentioned, the datatype of state is `String`, still I'm able to pass an integer value (1). It is converting `int` to `String` and accepting it, but vice versa it is not true. Wherever I have mentioned datatype as `String`, I'm able to pass `int` values. How to fix it? I need it to throw an error while passing an `int` value.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem clearly? and tell us how do you receive the request and what is the returned data in response

Comment: It would be helpful to know what libraries you are using for those annotations - I'm assuming it's Lombok for the class attributes and Jackson for deserialization. If so, and if I'm understanding your issue correctly, you could look at some of the solutions suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597779/prevent-automatic-string-to-integer-conversion-in-jackson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent automatic String to Integer conversion in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597779/prevent-automatic-string-to-integer-conversion-in-jackson)